# DB2:how to get top

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a table having data like

```
pin   id      name
3     33      jjj
2     22      bbb
1     111     aaaa
1     112     aa
1     113     aaa
4     44      kkk
```

I want to print rows of the table where if **count(*) group by pin**  =1 (i.e single entry in table ) print the row

if **count(*) group by pin**  >2 then print first two rows

so my out put should be

```
pin   id      name
3     33      jjj
2     22      bbb
1     111     aaaa
1     112     aa
4     44      kkk
```

Comment: Define "first".  SQL in general has no concept of inherent order, you must explicitly give an `ORDER BY` for results to have any sort of order.  What platform and version of DB2 - this will tell us what we can use.  Also, give us what you've tried so far, as this will show us what you're attempting to do.

Comment: You need to define the problem better or give more examples which will pin down exactly what you do (and dont) want, so that no room is left for alternate interpretations of what you might mean. Please be careful that you carefully follow the logic for your entire dataset. I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row_number() OVER(partion by pin order by id) as rownum [function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) . Where rownum <3
. As @Clockwork-Muse said, you need to define an order becase you need to say what do you want to see if there are more than 2 rows for a particular pin.
 This will generate you desired output.

Comment: This is rather opaque.  Yes, `ROW_NUMBER()` will likely be part of the solution, you could at least give a more concrete example - although you've missed one important piece to guarantee the likely ordering.  Oh, and your limiting comparison is wrong.